# ODBC connection issues with SQL Server

Tags: windows-server-2022, sql-server-2019-express, msodbcsql17

I have this configuration:

ABMES server on Windows Server 2022 Std and ABOEE SQL Server 2019 on Windows 2019 Std, both joined to domain.

I have configured on ABMES ODBC connection to ABOEE based ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

DSN name: `DB_OEEDB`, login by SQL Server user and password, no encryption.

I have connection from ABMES to ABOEE, tested from cmd:

```
sqlcmd -S ABOEE\SQLEXPRESS -U MES -P <password>
```

Connection established and working properly.

I tried connection by ODBC:

```
sqlcmd -S DB_OEEDB
```

and I get an error:

> Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. .
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server : Login timeout expired
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

Additionally, I checked Test Data Source... (in ODBC Microsoft SQL Server Setup after finish creation of connection) and I received message:

```
Connection established
Verifying option settings
INFO: A network alias was found for the DSN server.
;Protocol: DBMSSOCN: Address: ABOEE\SQLEXPRESS;
was used to establish the connection.
Disconnecting from server

TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!
```

What should I check/change/fix for set proper connection by ODBC?